# Let an unresolved async function executing on a nodejs server

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have a "recover password" option on a website. Sometimes my sendMail function takes a few seconds to execute. I want to call this async sendMail without waiting and return something like "check you inbox in a few seconds".

Will the server keep running the method or once it responds the method will be terminated?
Whatever happens will surely happen regardless if it's on Apache, Nginx, etc?

Comment: Can you show a relevant code snippet? If you're firing off an async callback, yes, it'll run after you return a response. In fact, it can't run while the call stack isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the sendMail method will keep running.   An incoming http request is just one asynchronous operation that nodejs can process.  It can have thousands of others going on too.  In this case, your `sendMail()` operation would be one additional asynchronous operation carrying on and it will finish without any regard for when the http request finishes.

Remember, nodejs is NOT a threaded architecture where each http request is a new thread that gets terminated at some point.  Instead, it's a non-blocking, event driven, asynchronous architecture and you can start as many other asynchronous operations as you want and they will run to completion regardless of what happens with the http request.